# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error shows up in VSCode

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

Whenever I run this code in VSCode.

```
class Employee{
    int salary;
    String name;

    public int getSalary(){
        return salary;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String n){
        name = n;
    }
}

public class ch8ps {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee test = new Employee();

        test.setName("XYZ");
        System.out.println(test.getName());
    }
}
```

It throws this error.

```
cd /home/linux/Desktop/Study\ Material/Codes/Java ; /usr/bin/env /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-19/bin/java @/tmp/cp_d5gr0ezmyf1mprctrtteedg
ec.argfile ch8ps 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void Employee.setName(java.lang.String)'
        at ch8ps.main(ch8ps.java:20)
```

and if I comment this line `test.setName("XYZ");` It returns same error for this `System.out.println(test.getName());` line too.

But, whenever I run this code in IntelliJ idea, it runs perfectly.

Comment: This error should only happen when compilation of `ch8ps` happened with a different version of `Employee` on the classpath than execution. Are both of those classes in the same file? Can you check if there's maybe more than one `Employee.class` anywhere in your output directory?

Comment: I'd say setName is not static, neither getNane, neither the string it sets too. You wouldn't getName  , do Employee.name in System.out. Put static on setName and the global.   If you want to stop static put Employee into the ch8p constructor with a global for it. Call your ch8p class with simply new ch8p();  recursively in its own main.